# SQL / Joomla Database

Tags: mysql, joomla3.0

I already have a database table called "form" I added a new field in same table.

The problem in query select * from "form" (php) while the old field display except the new field.

I have no idea why yet nothing displays the query is correct
the error is displayed :

```
 Undefined variable: Num in C:\xampp\htdocs\velocizzare\modules\mod_client\mod_client.php on line 96
Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\velocizzare\modules\mod_client\mod_client.php on line 96
```

the query is:

```
if(isset($_POST['BtnConsulter'])){
$_SESSION["del"]=$_POST['BtnConsulter'];
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$db = JFactory::getDBO(); 
$query=$db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*');
$query->from('ml0ak_chronoengine_chronoforms_datatable_formulaire');
$query->where('NuméroK10='.$_POST['BtnConsulter']);
$db->setQuery ($query); 
$users = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach ( $users as $us){

$Cognome=$us->Cognome;
$civilite=$us->civilite;
$Email=$us->Email;
$TelCellulaire=$us->TelCellulaire;
$AutreTel=$us->AutreTel;
$DataDiNascita=$us->DataDiNascita;
$Ville=$us->Ville;
$PaysNaissance=$us->PaysNaissance;
$ResidenteInCitta=$us->ResidenteInCitta;
$Provincia=$us->Provincia;
$Num->$us->Num;
);
echo"<br />Nome: $Nome";
echo"<br />Cognome: $Cognome";
echo"<br />E-mail: $Email";
echo"<br />Tel/Cellulare: $TelCellulaire";
echo"<br />Autre Tel: $AutreTel";
echo"<br />Data di nascita: $DataDiNascita";
echo"<br />Ville: $Ville";
echo"<br />Pays de Naissance: $PaysNaissance";
echo"<br />Residente in (Citta): $ResidenteInCitta";
echo"<br />Provincia: $Provincia";
echo"<br /> Num: $Num";
```

[image]
Please what's solution ?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: are you storing the data in cache? If yes then you need to clear the cache data.

Comment: I do not store data in the cache
I also clear all data no change

Comment: did you check the result of you query in terminal ?

Comment: yes the result of query is  same error. the old field display and the new not displate